# Switching Views in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, switch-statement

How come this won't switch views for me? When I click the button it does nothing...

```
-(IBAction)howtoplayButtonClicked{
    howToPlayViewController = [[HowToPlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HowToPlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:howToPlayViewController animated:YES];
    [HowToPlayViewController release];

}
```

in the .h file I have this...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HowToPlayViewController.h"

@interface PopToItViewController : UIViewController {

    HowToPlayViewController *howToPlayViewController;

}

-(IBAction)howtoplayButtonClicked;

@end
```

Comment: Did you connect your button to the action method howtoplayButtonClicked?

Comment: Did you verify with an NSLog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action method...

```
-(IBAction)howtoplayButtonClicked;
```

... should look like this:

```
-(IBAction)howtoplayButtonClicked:(id) sender;
```

In it's improper form it might not be called. If correcting the form does not work, you should:

1. Put a breakpoint or log statement in the method to see if it ever gets called. If it does not check you IBConnections to make sure the button is wired to the method.
2. You don't need `howToPlayViewController` set as property if your initializing it from nib and then releasing it. Generally you would only use a property if you wanted to wire it up in Interface Builder in which case it should be defined like so:

   `IBOutlet HowToPlayViewController *howToPlayViewController;`

Answer (score 2):

For starters, this is wrong:

```
[HowToPlayViewController release];
```

It should be:

```
[howToPlayViewController release];
```

I don't know what sending a release message to a Class does.

Comment: switched it howtoPlayViewController and it's still not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

Make sure self.navigationController!=nil

Comment: for example assert(self.navigationController != nil)

Answer (score 0):

Set `initWithNibName:nil"`  and let the view controller do the rest.

Comment: if you want the flip animation you can add  yourViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; just change the UIModalTransitionStyle for any other animation.